# How to check when you scanf that you get only integer (like 2) and not integer followed by char (like 2c)

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to scanf an integer to see if it's legal in my program. However, if I input a number followed by a char it still treats it as legal number (my guess is that it only refers to the integer while saving the char in the buffer). Assume I can only use scanf and not something else (since that's what we've leraned). Also, if I input only a char it automatically casts it to an integer. This is what I have tried so far, with the help of what I saw here -

```
 int number_of_numbers;
 char number='\n';
 printf("Enter size of input:");
 if (scanf("%d%c",&number_of_numbers, &number)>=1 && number!='\n')
    {
        printf("Invalid size");
        return 0;
    }
```

How can I identify when I scanf only an integer or an integer followed by a char or just a char?
Thanks!

Comment: get input with `fgets()`, parse with `strtoul()` or similar and/or `isalpha()` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter "only a character" it does not "automatically cast it to an integer". It does not accept *any input at all*, as shown by scanf returning `0`, but that situation escapes your test.

But the answer to your question is: **with difficulty** when using `scanf`.

Here is a way to do it getting the input with `fgets`. It will tolerate any amount of whitespace before or after the number, but not any letters.

The reason for the space before `%c` is to instruct it to filter any leading whitespace. This is automatic anyway for `%d`, but not for `%c`. Then if there are no readable characters, nothing will be read into `extra`. If there is at least one character (apart from whitespace) then the `sscanf` conversion count will be incorrect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{
    int number_of_numbers = 0;
    while(number_of_numbers >= 0) {
        bool success = false;
        char str[100];
        if(fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) != NULL) {
            char extra;
            if(sscanf(str, "%d %c", &number_of_numbers, &extra) == 1) {
                success = true;
            }
        }
        if(success) {
            printf("Success: %d\n\n", number_of_numbers);
        } else {
            printf("Invalid size\n\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program session:

```
123
Success: 123

123a
Invalid size

123 a
Invalid size

123 9
Invalid size

a
Invalid size

-1
Success: -1
```

The reasons for using `fgets` are

- it doesn't "stall" if there is invalid input: it has already been read.
- if there is a mistake, the string can easily be dumped and another one requested.